# Give factors numerical value [R]

Tags: r, prediction, numerical, r-factor

I want to predict a numerical variable. I have a couple of factors. For all that factors I have a numerical equivalent. Now it would be perfect to assign that numerical equivalent to the factor and use it in the prediction. Is this possible?
If this is not possible I guess I will need to replace the factors with their numerical equivalent. What is the best way to do so?

An Example:

```
df = data.frame(f=c("a","b","a","c"),v=c(2,4,2,6))
lookup = data.frame(name=c("a","b","c"),v=c(1,2,3))
```

What I would like to get

```
df2 = data.frame(f=c(1,2,1,3),v=c(2,4,2,6))
cor(df2$f,df2$v) # will be 1
```

Comment: How do you mean, the factors have numerical equivalents? Factors are categories. When you say prediction, what do you mean?

Comment: R treats factors as categorical variables and numeric values as continuous variables. The two types of variables often have different statistical methods associated with them and the interpretation of a model differs by variable type. You really should decide what type of analysis is appropriate for your data first.

Comment: I added an example to make it more clear. The letters are what I got, the numbers in the lookup-table some average values I calculated before and would like to use now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Or

```
df2 <- merge(df, lookup, by.x = "f", by.y = "name")
cor(df2[, 2], df2[, 3])
```

Or if your data sets are big

```
library(data.table)
setkey(setDT(df), f)
setkey(setDT(lookup), name)
df2 <- df[lookup]
cor(df2[, 2, with = F], df2[, 3, with = F])
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this help?

```
cor(lookup$v[match(df$f,lookup$name)],df$v)
```

Comment: thanks, that works as well, but only if there is only one column needed for identification. I need more (even that is was not included in my example)